# wi fi connection

Tags: wireless

Hey what's up ubuntu users. I would like ask you about wi fi connection on ubuntu. After cracking my router because i forgot my password, I can't get stable connection with it. It finds my router however shows that the low signal even it is next to router and can't connect. If it does there is no internet connection. I am sure my router is working because smartphones and computers connect, but notebook on Ubuntu OS can't do it. Can you help me.I am using LTE 16

Comment: what is the model of your router?